# What is this comic featuring a man whose eyes see two different versions of the world?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I would have read it in the mid-90s, but I'm not sure if was new at that time. The main character of the series sees the world normally through one eye, but the other shows a demonic version of things. He wears an eye patch to switch back and forth.

In the issue I read, he goes to visit his mother(I think) in a hospital. While there, a priest joins him in an elevator and pushes the button for the basement. Looking at the priest with the "demon" eye reveals him as a demon. The priest-demon is killed with a shovel of hot coals to the face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are referring to [Ectokid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectokid), part of the Razorline series, an imprint of Marvel.

The series only ran from Sep 1993 to May 1994.  This matches your timeline.

The star is Dexter Mungo whose mother was human but his father was a ghost.  His right eye sees into the normal world, but his left eye sees into the Ectosphere.  One of the side effects of this ability, is that he can see through the disguises of demons.

It has been a while since I have read the comic, but your events (visit mother in hospital, finding that priest is a demon, killing the demon with hot coals) occur in the first issue of the series.